# How do i get this javascript section to work

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I’m creating a mock website using html, Javascript and CSS. I want to move from one page to another (home.html to TVShows.html) by pressing on the list “TV Shows” on navigation bar. Usually i’d just assign href but i want to code this interaction using Javascript instead. Here’s my attempt but it doesn't work.
Html:

```
<li><a id="TVShows" href="#">TV
        Shows</a></li>
```

Javascript:

```
// Function to handle navigation to TV Shows page
document.getElementById('TVShows').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent default link behavior
    console.log("TV Shows link clicked");
    // Redirect to TV Shows page
    window.location.href = 'TVShows.html'; 
});
```

I’ve tried different methods of writing this none have worked.

Comment: It works for me, which suggests that the error is elsewhere.

Comment: I’ve confirmed that the names and labels are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>

<li><a id="TVShows" href="#">TV
        Shows</a></li>

<script>
// Function to handle navigation to TV Shows page
document.getElementById('TVShows').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent default link behavior
    console.log("TV Shows link clicked");
    // Redirect to TV Shows page
    window.location.href = 'TVShows.html'; 
});
</script>
```

This standalone page works. So the error is elsewhere, in some other code you've not shown us.

Comment: I found the issue. I was using one javascript file for all the pages and calling the same .js src on each html file. Seems like you need separate .js files for each html or write the script directly in the html. Thanks

Comment: A single shared file should generally work. There are occasions where it might not, probably for some other reason, or because different functions within the script are conflicting in some way. As a general rule, though, it should work.

Comment: I assumed so but in this case i dont know why it didnt. I made sure nothing was conflicting

Answer (score 0):

make sure that your script is at the end of your html file, otherwise the element might not exist yet (because not loaded) or you can also use this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var tvShowsLink = document.getElementById('TVShows');
    tvShowsLink.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("TV Shows link clicked");
        window.location.href = 'TVShows.html';
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I was using one javascript file for all the pages and calling the same .js src on each html file. Seems like you need separate .js files for each html or write the script directly in the html.